# Solving for an unknown value in inequalities

Tags: inequality, discriminant

**Q: Find the values of  for which the quadratic expression
4^2 + 12 −  is always positive.**

What I’ve tried:

The discriminant is > 0 therefore
b^2-4ac>0

a=4
b=12k
c=-k

This resulted in:
12k^2+16k>0

I am not sure where to go next to solve for the value of ‘k’, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Well, solve that inequality. Set $12k^2+16k=0$ and find the $2$ k-values. Since this quadratic resembles a "parabola" that opens up, you should find someting like $k<...$ and $k>...$

Comment: The discriminat is $144k^2+16k$ or $(12k)^2+16k$.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify a bit  the computations using the *reduced* discriminant:
$$\Delta'=(6k)^2+4k=4k(9k+1)$$
The quadratic polynomial $4x^2 + 12x − $ has a constant sign (that of the leading coefficient) if & only if $\Delta'<0$. As the leading coefficient of $\Delta'$ (as a quadratic polynomial in $k$) is positive, this means $k$ belongs to the interval of the roots, namely $\;\bigl(-\frac19,0\bigr)$.